# In Python, is there an elegant way to print a list in a custom format without explicit looping?

Tags: python, list

I know you can do

```
print str(myList)
```

to get

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

and you can do

```
i = 0
for entry in myList:
  print str(i) + ":", entry
  i += 1
```

to get

```
0: 1  
1: 2  
2: 3
```

But is there a way similar to the first to get a result similar to the last?

With my limited knowledge of Python (and some help from the documentation), my best is:

```
print '\n'.join([str(n) + ": " + str(entry) for (n, entry) in zip(range(0,len(myList)), myList)])
```

It's not much less verbose, but at least I get a custom string in one (compound) statement.
Can you do better?

Comment: Looks like one has to write their own utility function and use it elegantly where necessary, this will also keep your code cleaner to read than those cramped one-liner solutions (or you can make such a one-liner your function for that).

Answer (score 131, accepted):

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print('\n'.join('{}: {}'.format(*k) for k in enumerate(lst)))
0: 1
1: 2
2: 3
```

Note: you just need to understand that list comprehension or iterating over a generator expression **is** explicit looping.

Comment: More explicitly: Losing the square brackets makes it a generator expression, so it doesn't create the whole list in memory before building a string from it. And enumerate is a built in function to do the same as the poster's zip/range/len combo.

Comment: "Note: you just need to understand that list comprehension or iterating over a generator expression is explicit looping." I think your concept of "explicit" is radically different from mine. List comprehensions are declarative and/or functional rather than imperative.

Comment: @SilentGhost: thanks, I am on a system with python2.6.  I ended up using "print '\n'.join('entry {0}: {1}'.format(i+1, entry) for i, entry in enumerate(entries))" (I actually needed an offset of 1)

Comment: @stefaan: `enumerate` has a `start` parameter, so you could just do: `print('\n'.join('entry {0}: {1}'.format(*k) for k in enumerate(entries, 1)))` and it's a good idea to start using `print` function over `print` statement.

Comment: @Karl: I don't think that declarativeness is contradictory to explicitness.

Comment: @SilentGhost: brilliant, I changed it.

Answer (score 40):

In python 3s print function:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
print('My list:', *lst, sep='\n- ')
```

Output:

```
My list:
- 1
- 2
- 3
```

**Con**: The `sep` must be a string, so you can't modify it based on which element you're printing. And you need a kind of *header* to do this (above it was `'My list:'`).

**Pro**: You don't have to `join()` a list into a string object, which might be advantageous for larger lists. And the whole thing is quite concise and readable.

Answer (score 10):

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
print '\n'.join(['%i: %s' % (n, l[n]) for n in xrange(len(l))])
```

Comment: I'm shocked how many people seemingly don't know `enumerate`.

Comment: @delnan: I don't know it either, probably because I don't use python enough (tests and scripting).  I'll look into it now.

Answer (score 8):

Starting from this:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print('\n'.join('{}: {}'.format(*k) for k in enumerate(lst)))
0: 1
1: 2
2: 3
```

You can get rid of the `join` by passing `\n` as a separator to `print`

```
>>> print(*('{}: {}'.format(*k) for k in enumerate(lst)), sep="\n")
0: 1
1: 2
2: 3
```

Now you see you could use `map`, but you'll need to change the format string (yuck!)

```
>>> print(*(map('{0[0]}: {0[1]}'.format, enumerate(lst))), sep="\n")
0: 1
1: 2
2: 3
```

or pass 2 sequences to `map`. A separate counter and no longer enumerate `lst`

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> print(*(map('{}: {}'.format, count(), lst)), sep="\n")
0: 1
1: 2
2: 3
```

Comment: only fist syntax is for py 2.x all other for py 3x

Comment: @BombaPs, The others can work for 2.x if you use `from __future__ import print_function`

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> from itertools import starmap

>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print('\n'.join(starmap('{}: {}'.format, enumerate(lst))))
0: 1
1: 2
2: 3
```

This uses `itertools.starmap`, which is like `map`, except it `*`s the argument into the function. The function in this case is `'{}: {}'.format`.

I would prefer the comprehension of SilentGhost, but `starmap` is a nice function to know about.

Answer (score 3):

Another:

```
>>> lst=[10,11,12]
>>> fmt="%i: %i"
>>> for d in enumerate(lst):
...    print(fmt%d)
... 
0: 10
1: 11
2: 12
```

Yet another form:

```
>>> for i,j in enumerate(lst): print "%i: %i"%(i,j)
```

That method is nice since the individual elements in tuples produced by [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) can be modified such as:

```
>>> for i,j in enumerate([3,4,5],1): print "%i^%i: %i "%(i,j,i**j)
... 
1^3: 1 
2^4: 16 
3^5: 243
```

Of course, don't forget you can get a slice from this like so:

```
>>> for i,j in list(enumerate(lst))[1:2]: print "%i: %i"%(i,j)
... 
1: 11
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with explicit looping.  I was just wondering what the alternatives were.

Answer (score 3):

```
from time import clock
from random import sample

n = 500
myList = sample(xrange(10000),n)
#print myList

A,B,C,D = [],[],[],[]

for i in xrange(100):
    t0 = clock()
    ecr =( '\n'.join('{}: {}'.format(*k) for k in enumerate(myList)) )
    A.append(clock()-t0)

    t0 = clock()
    ecr = '\n'.join(str(n) + ": " + str(entry) for (n, entry) in zip(range(0,len(myList)), myList))
    B.append(clock()-t0)

    t0 = clock()
    ecr = '\n'.join(map(lambda x: '%s: %s' % x, enumerate(myList)))
    C.append(clock()-t0)

    t0 = clock()
    ecr = '\n'.join('%s: %s' % x for x in enumerate(myList))
    D.append(clock()-t0)

print '\n'.join(('t1 = '+str(min(A))+'   '+'{:.1%}.'.format(min(A)/min(D)),
                 't2 = '+str(min(B))+'   '+'{:.1%}.'.format(min(B)/min(D)),
                 't3 = '+str(min(C))+'   '+'{:.1%}.'.format(min(C)/min(D)),
                 't4 = '+str(min(D))+'   '+'{:.1%}.'.format(min(D)/min(D))))
```

For n=500:

```
150.8%.
142.7%.
110.8%.
100.0%.
```

For n=5000:

```
153.5%.
176.2%.
109.7%.
100.0%.
```

Oh, I see now: only the solution 3 with map() fits with the title of the question.

Comment: Nice research.  Generator expression isn't explicit looping, so they all count with 1 and 4 being my favorites, with 1 using a more powerful, but as here show, slower formatting.  Merci.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pprint.html), The pprint module provides a capability to “pretty-print” arbitrary Python data structures in a form which can be used as input to the interpreter. If the formatted structures include objects which are not fundamental Python types, the representation may not be loadable. This may be the case if objects such as files, sockets or classes are included, as well as many other objects which are not representable as Python literals.

```
>>> import pprint
>>> stuff = ['spam', 'eggs', 'lumberjack', 'knights', 'ni']
>>> stuff.insert(0, stuff[:])
>>> pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
>>> pp.pprint(stuff)
[   ['spam', 'eggs', 'lumberjack', 'knights', 'ni'],
    'spam',
    'eggs',
    'lumberjack',
    'knights',
    'ni']
>>> pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(width=41, compact=True)
>>> pp.pprint(stuff)
[['spam', 'eggs', 'lumberjack',
  'knights', 'ni'],
 'spam', 'eggs', 'lumberjack', 'knights',
 'ni']
>>> tup = ('spam', ('eggs', ('lumberjack', ('knights', ('ni', ('dead',
... ('parrot', ('fresh fruit',))))))))
>>> pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(depth=6)
>>> pp.pprint(tup)
('spam', ('eggs', ('lumberjack', ('knights', ('ni', ('dead', (...)))))))
```

Comment: pprint is not not only for lists (as OP was asking), but for much more