# Python list printing (formatting)

Tags: python-2.7

Having a list:

```
x=['s',2,'3',4,5,6]
```

I can print it like this:

```
for i in x:
        print i
```

However, as I've found out, it's a bit faster to just use one print statement, like this (below is how I got to this point):

```
print "\n".join( i.__class__==string and i or str(i) for i in x )
```

***Given that I want to use the second option and that I would like the output to be something like (I would also like to include a counter):
`v1: s v2: 2 v3: 3 etc`***

Here is what I've tried:

**1)**

```
count=0
print (("v"+str(++count)).join(":%s "% i for i in x  ) )
```

result is:`:s, v0:2, v0:3, v0:4, v0:5, v0:6,`  Really not what I'm aiming for.

a) str(++count) prints nothing, count++ gives synthax error

b) first `v` is nowhere to be found, since `join` in this case adds separators and there is no need for the first element

**2)**

```
print ( ["v"+str(++count)+ ":%s, "% i for i in x ] )
```

Gives `['v0:s, ', 'v0:2, ', 'v0:3, ', 'v0:4, ', 'v0:5, ', 'v0:6, ']` Better, but still no `counter` and I don't want the `[]` being shown

**3)**
Scratch all and restart:

```
print ",".join(i  for i in x )
```

cannot concatenate `string` and `int` so it becomes:

```
print ",".join(i.__class__==string and i or str(i)  for i in x )
```

which gives:

```
s,2,3,4,5,6
```

**And here is where I'm stuck.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python, is there an elegant way to print a list in a custom format without explicit looping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440516/in-python-is-there-an-elegant-way-to-print-a-list-in-a-custom-format-without-ex)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest to use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
x = ['s',2,'3',4,5,6]
print ', '.join('v{}: {}'.format(v, i) for v, i in enumerate(x))
# v0: s, v1: 2, v2: 3, v3: 4, v4: 5, v5: 6
```

Answer (score 2):

While I agree with @ARodas's answer, I'd like to also point out that:

1. You need to make sure printing is really a bottleneck in your program before starting to optimize it (it very rarely is).
2. `expr1 and expr2 or expr3` was used prior to Python 2.5, when `expr2 if expr1 else expr3` ternary operator was introduced. If you do not target Py <= 2.4, `if else` is preferable.
3. Instead of `i.__class__==string` it is better to write `isinstance(i, string)` (what is `string`, anyway? Did you mean `str`?).
4. Moreover, you do not really need to check that: `str()` of a string just returns this string.
5. There is no `++` operator in Python. `++count == +(+count) == count`.