# Formatting the printing of list concatenated with other variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list *data* and its *mean*, *median* and *mode* as below:

```
data = [2, 3, 5, 5, 7, -6, -6, 9]
mean = 2.00
median = 3.00
mode = [5, -6]
```

I want to have a neat Pythonic output of the results. Using the answers recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440516/in-python-is-there-an-elegant-way-to-print-a-list-in-a-custom-format-without-ex) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400015/python-list-printing-formatting) I have come up with the following code.

```
print('Mean:{0:9.2f}\nMedian:{1:7.2f}'.format(mean, median),
  ''.join('\nMode: {}: {}'.format(*k) for k in enumerate(mode)))
```

However, I'm not confident if this is a good solution anyway and my output looks like this:

```
Mean:     2.38
Median:   4.00 
Mode: 0: -6
Mode: 1: 5
```

I want an output like:

```
Mean:     2.38
Median:   4.00
Mode:     -6, 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`format()` can still be used as follows:

```
data = [2, 3, 5, 5, 7, -6, -6, 9]
mean = 2.00
median = 3.00
mode = [5, -6]

print('Mean:   {:.2f}\nMedian: {:.2f}\nMode:   {}'.format(mean, median, ', '.join(map(str, mode))))
```

Giving you:

```
Mean:   2.00
Median: 3.00
Mode:   5, -6
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just use tabs:

```
print('Mean:\t{}\nMedian:\t{}\nMode:\t{}'.format(mean,median,', '.join(str(i) for i in mode)))
```

giving:

```
Mean:   2.0
Median: 3.0
Mode:   5, -6
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.ljust()` to make sure your titles (e.g. `Mean`, `Median`) have a fixed length:

```
TITLE_LENGTH = 10
print("Mean:".ljust(TITLE_LENGTH) + "{:.2f}".format(mean))
print("Median:".ljust(TITLE_LENGTH) + "{:.2f}".format(median))
print("Mode:".ljust(TITLE_LENGTH) + "{}: {}".format(mode[0], mode[1]))
```

Output:

```
Mean:     2.00
Median:   3.00
Mode:     5: -6
```

Comment: thanks for introducing str.ljust() I like your way of formatting title fields better, however your solution doesn't take into consideration that there might be 1 mode data or more than 2 --> .format(mode[0], mode[1])

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I chose to remove the "mode" loop to simplify the code. The fact that the mode has 2 elements or more is outside of the scope of this question.