# common lisp like format directive to print lists

Tags: python, formatting, common-lisp

***Disclaimer***: *The question how to print a list in python is already covered multiple times, thus, this question does NOT ask HOW to print a list BUT WHETHER a specific way to print a list exists (using the format directive).*

The first hit one gets googling how to print a list using `format` in python is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440516/in-python-is-there-an-elegant-way-to-print-a-list-in-a-custom-format-without-ex) and it looks like:

```
print('\n'.join('{}'.format(k) for k in lst))
```

is the way to go. But I keep wondering if there is a lisp like format directive to do this without the verbose join operation. E.g. in [common lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/a-few-format-recipes.html) one would simple write:

```
(FORMAT T "~%~{~a~%~}" list-i-want-printed)
```

`~{...~}` basically means iterate over list

`~a` basically means to take one argument and print it using its (or the default) print/to-string directive

`~%` newline

**Does such a format directive exist in python?**

As a more thorough example why I'd like to use such directive:
Given you have 3 lists you want to print below each other. The lisp `FORMAT` would allow:

```
(FORMAT T "~{~a~}~%~{~a~}~%~{~a~}~%" list-1 list-2 list-3)
```

whereas the python solution would look like:

```
print(''.join('{}'.format(k) for k in lsta) + '\n' + ''.join('{}'.format(k) for k in lstb) + '\n' + ''.join('{}'.format(k) for k in lstc))
```

not quite as refined.

Comment: A simple `print(lst)` will print a list, and `print(lsta, lstb, lstc)` will print 3 lists, one per line. I suppose that's the closest thing to what your lisp code does, but I don't know lisp. It's not clear how you want the output to look, since your two Python snippets produce quite different results.

Comment: It is not about a specific output but rather the General notion of using a print list directive inside a Format string to habe a short statement instead of multiple joins. Basically i want to be able to Format a list within abitrary context.

Comment: You can print the list as a single entity, in which case you get its string representation, complete with brackets and commas between the `repr` of each list item. If that's not adequate then I'm afraid you'll have to do some form of looping. Note that you can join a list (or other container) of strings with `sep.join(str_lst)`, where `str_lst` is the list of strings and `sep` is the string used to separate the string items in `str_lst`.

Comment: Of course, `.join` still performs a loop (actually it performs 2 loops: one to calculate the size of the destination string, and one to build that string), but those loops happen at C speed, so they're substantially faster than loops written in Python.

Comment: FWIW, Python provides two standard "to string" functions: `str()` and `repr()`. These functions invoke an object's `__str__` and `__repr__` methods. The former returns a user-friendly string representation of the object, the latter is mostly for use by developers and it should give an accurate representation of the contents of the object, ideally something that can be used to re-create the object. If an object doesn't have a `__str__` method then `str()` will invoke its `__repr__`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the basic answer is "No", but you can refine your example a bit:

```
print( ' '.join(  '{}'.format(k) for k in lsta+lstb+lstc  ) )
```

No newlines. If I wanted a newline after each list I'd do

```
for lst in (lsta,lstb,lstc):
    print( ' '.join(  '{}'.format(k) for k in lst  ) )
```