# Strange nested loop behavior while handling an exception

Tags: python, file

Goal: if count is larger than actual line count, in `except` block: tell user and have them press enter. set `count` equal to total number of lines in file and retry the loop.

```
count = 10000
with open('mobydick_ch1.txt') as f:

        while 1:
            lines = []
            try:
                for i in range(count):
                    lines.append(next(f))  # iterate through file and append each line in range
                    break
            except StopIteration:
                if not input("File does not contain that many lines, press enter to continue printing maximum lines:"):
                    for i, k in enumerate(f, 1):
                        count = i

        f.close()  # close file

        # format output. enumerate lines, start at 1
        # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440516/in-python-is-there-an-elegant-
        # way-to-print-a-list-in-a-custom-format-without-ex
    print(''.join('Line {0}: {1}'.format(*k) for k in enumerate(lines, 1)))
```

I am currently getting:

> File does not contain that many lines, press enter to continue printing maximum lines:

every time I press enter. What is causing this unwanted behavior?

Comment: The `f.close()` is entirely redundant; you are already using the file as a context manager (`with ...`)

Comment: What is the goal of that `for i,  k in enumerate(f, 1): count = i` loop anyway? Are you trying to set `count` to the actual number of lines in the file if less than 10000?

Comment: I'm not certain I understand why you are using an infinite loop. Is the goal to wait for the file to get more lines? You can't without re-opening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already exhausted the file, you can't then read from the file *again* without seeking back to 0. As a result your `for i, k in enumerate(f, 1):` loop exits immediately. The same then applies to every future iteration of your `while 1:` loop; the file is still at the end and all access with `next()` will raise a `StopIteration` immediately.

You already know how many lines you have read, just set `count = len(lines)`. There is no need to read the whole file *again* just to set `count`.

It'd be better if you used [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to get your 1000 lines:

```
from itertools import islice

count = 10000
with open('mobydick_ch1.txt') as f:
    lines = list(islice(f, count))  # list of up to count lines
if len(lines) < count:
    input("File does not contain that many lines, press enter to continue printing maximum lines:")
    count = len(lines)  # set count to actual number of lines
```

If you are trying to *wait* until a file contains at least `count` lines, you'll have to re-open the file each time and seek to the last recorded location:

```
lines = []
pos = 0
while len(lines) < count:
    with open('mobydick_ch1.txt') as f:
        f.seek(pos)
        lines.extend(islice(f, count - len(lines)))
        pos = f.tell()
    if len(lines) < count:
        input("File does not contain that many lines, press enter to continue printing maximum lines:")
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not sure what you mean by showing lines in `lines` if the list is empty until getting past the exception. I tried placing `f.seek(0)` right above `for i, k in enumerate(f, 1):` and am getting the same result

Comment: @A.Michael: `StopIteration` is raised only when there are no more lines. All lines *up to that point* are added to the `lines` list. If `lines` is empty, then that means there were no lines *at all* in the file, i.e. the file was *empty to start with*.

Comment: @A.Michael: ah, you are looping endlessly without re-opening the file...

Comment: @Marijn Thanks for your help and time. I can definitely work with what you gave me. Learned a good deal about files along the way!