# Python formatting a table through loop with a guide list

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I have a list of tags below.

```
mytags = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

And, I have a file with strings like this in a list format.

```
['a-1',   'b-3',  'c-4',  'e-3']
['a-10', 'b-12', 'c-14', 'd-16']
['b-1',   'c-5', 'd-13',  'f-7']
```

I would like to print the file as a tab-delimited table in order of the tags in mylist like this.

```
#header
#a,   b,   c,   d,   e,  f
 a-1  b-3  c-4  NA   e-3 NA
 a-10 b-12 c-14 d-16 NA  NA
 NA   b-1  c-5  d-13 NA  f-7
```

I wrote a python code, but the nested double loop gives an unwanted result.

```
print (mylist)

for lineList in file:
    for tag in mytags:
        if tag in lineList:
            print(lineList, end="\t")
        else:
            print("NA", end="\t")
```

How can I make the table with those data?

Comment: Have you considered pandas? The formatting with dataframes is pretty nice and will provide you the header and column names that you got commented in the expected output.

If not, you will have to use format. Plenty of examples here: https://pyformat.info/ or in this question which has some similaritiesr to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440516/in-python-is-there-an-elegant-way-to-print-a-list-in-a-custom-format-without-ex

Comment: "but the nested double loop gives an unwanted result." <- which is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could use `setdefault` here

```
my_tags = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
line_list = [
    ['a-1',   'b-3',  'c-4',  'e-3'],
    ['a-10', 'b-12', 'c-14', 'd-16'],
    ['b-1',   'c-5', 'd-13',  'f-7']
]

for lst in line_list:
    d = {i[0]: i for i in lst}
    for i in my_tags:
        print(d.setdefault(i, 'NA'), end ='\t')
    print()


a-1     b-3     c-4     NA      e-3     NA  
a-10    b-12    c-14    d-16    NA      NA  
NA      b-1     c-5     d-13    NA      f-7
```

Comment: if I import the line_list from outside, then the last line is missing. So far this looks the best answer once the problem is fixed. Thank you very much for the nice code.

Comment: @Karyo your welcome hope it all works, hmm cant think of why that would be the case, could you load everything from outside into a list then perform this, still should work though hmm

Comment: ! Oh my bad. Forgot to close the write function. This code works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Karyo there we go, awesome :)

Answer (score 3):

You should extract the tags from the items before you make comparison to your list of tags:

```
mytags = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
rows = [
    ['a-1',   'b-3',  'c-4',  'e-3'],
    ['a-10', 'b-12', 'c-14', 'd-16'],
    ['b-1',   'c-5', 'd-13',  'f-7']
]
for row in rows:
    for tag in mytags:
        print(row.pop(0) if row and row[0].split('-')[0] == tag else 'NA', end='\t')
    print()
```

or with generator expressions:

```
print('\n'.join('\t'.join(row.pop(0) if row and row[0].split('-')[0] == tag else 'NA' for tag in mytags) for row in rows))
```

Comment: You can use `collection.defaultdict` to make it more simple.

Answer (score 1):

since the strings will be in a file so below is my approach

```
# read the file
data = pd.read_csv('test.txt', header=None,sep='[')

master_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c','d','e','f'])

for i in range(len(data)):
    master_df.loc[i] = 'NA'
    temp = data[1][i].replace(']','')
    temp = temp.replace("'",'')
    for char in temp.split(','):
        master_df[char.split('-')[0].strip()][i] = char

print(master_df)
```

Output

```
      a       b       c      d      e      f
0   a-1     b-3     c-4     NA    e-3     NA
1  a-10    b-12    c-14   d-16     NA     NA
2    NA     b-1     c-5   d-13     NA    f-7
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an understandable and easy way using `re`(**Regular Expressions**) to do what you described but you should just get the file's text without any special reading like `csv_reader` or anything else, so just read the file using `open` function, let's start:-

```
import re

filetext = """['a-1',   'b-3',  'c-4',  'e-3']
['a-10', 'b-12', 'c-14', 'd-16']
['b-1',   'c-5', 'd-13',  'f-7']"""

#find all values
values = re.findall(r'\w+-\d+', filetext)
values.sort()

#find tags
tags = []
for i in values:
    if(tags.count(i.split('-')[0])==0):
        tags.append(i.split('-')[0])

#find max length
maxLength = max([len(list(filter(lambda a:a.split('-')[0]==i, values))) for i in tags])

#create a list with the results
result = [[] for i in tags]
ind=-1
for i in tags:
    ind+=1
    for j in values:
        if(j.split('-')[0]==i):
            result[ind].append(j)

#add 'NA' for non complete lists
for i in result:
    i.sort(key=lambda v:int(v.split('-')[1]))
    if(len(i)!=maxLength):
        for j in range(maxLength - len(i)):
            i.append('NA')

#print them as you liked
for i in tags:
    print(i, end='\t')

print()

for i in range(maxLength):
    for j in result:
        print(j[i], end='\t')
    print()
```

**Result**

```
a      b      c      d       e      f    
a-1    b-1    c-4    d-13    e-3    f-7    
a-10   b-3    c-5    d-16    NA     NA   
NA     b-12   c-14   NA      NA     NA
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but the result does not match what I wanted. The values supposed to be in the same line, not in the other lines.